# я уже долго решаю задачу муравей и дерево но оно проходит лишь на 55% ПОМОГИТЕ пожалуйчта разобраться

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
#include<math.h>
#include<string>
#include<vector>
#include<queue>
#include<map>
#include<set>
#include <stdio.h>

#define PI 3.14159265
using namespace std;
double leg(int a,int a1,int b,int b1)
{
    a=abs(a-b);
    b=abs(a1-b1);
    return sqrt(a*a+b*b);      
}


int main()
{
    int a,a1,b,b1,d,d1;
    double f,s,f1,s1,m,x,y,z,r,k,p;
    float u;
    cin>>a>>a1>>b>>b1>>d>>d1>>r;
    u=r;
    f=leg(a,a1,d,d1);
    s=leg(b,b1,d,d1);
    m=leg(b,b1,a,a1);

    f1=sqrt(f*f-r*r);
    s1=sqrt(s*s-r*r);

    x=acos(r/f)*180.0/PI;
    y=acos(r/s)*180.0/PI;
    z=acos((m*m-(f*f+s*s))/(-1*(2*f*s)))*180.0/PI;

    z=z-(x+y);

    z=(2*PI*r*z)/360;
    p=(f+s+m)/2;
    k=(2*sqrt(p*(p-f)*(p-s)*(p-m)))/m;
    float q;
    q=k;
    if(u>q)
    cout<<fixed<<setprecision(3)<<f1+s1+z<<endl;
    else cout<<m<<endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Оформление кода на высоте

Comment: Опишите задачу, опишите, в чём проблема, и отформатируйте код.

Comment: Как я понимаю, задачу вы считаете столь общеизвестной, что ее должен знать любой?...

Comment: @Harry любой ... муравей. Или дерево :)

Comment: @alexolut Любой дуб :) Кстати, умиляет перевод радиан в градусы и назад :)

Comment: [Задумчиво] Интересно, зачем в `leg` применяется `abs`?...

Answer (score 1):

Ладно уж, суббота, отдыхаю... :)

```
inline double dist2(double x, double y){ return x*x+y*y; }
inline double dist(double x, double y) { return sqrt(dist2(x,y)); }
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    double x1, y1, x2, y2, x, y, r;
    cin >> x1 >> y1 >> x2 >> y2 >> x >> y >> r;
    x1 -= x; y1 -= y; x2 -= x; y2 -= y;
    x = acos(r/dist(x1,y1)) + acos(r/dist(x2,y2));
    y = acos((x1*x2+y1*y2)/(dist(x1,y1)*dist(x2,y2))) - x;
    if (y < 0)
        y = dist(x1-x2,y1-y2);
    else
        y = sqrt(dist2(x1,y1)-r*r) + sqrt(dist2(x2,y2)-r*r) + y*r;
    cout << y << endl;
}
```

Только учтите, что это решение уже заняло 1 место на www.e-olymp.com, так что просто передрать будет очень некорректно с вашей стороны :)